# Update state in deep structure not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just got started with React+Redux and I have a problem.
I know that I am never supposed to alter the old state in the reducer and I am not doing that.

However, when I change a variable like this in my reducer, my component is not re-rendering, even though I have mapStateToProps with state.coupons

```
// this deep copies everything
let newState = Object.assign({}, state);

newState.coupons[2].events[0].eventRows[0].alternatives[0].selected = true;

return newState;
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I even tested to use `newState = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(oldState))` but with no success

EDIT:
This is my mapStateToProps function

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  coupons: state.coupons,
  currentDraw: state.currentDraw
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the solution in redux docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-nested-objects

> The key to updating nested data is **that *every* level of nesting must be
>   copied and updated appropriately**. This is often a difficult concept
>   for those learning Redux, and there are some specific problems that
>   frequently occur when trying to update nested objects. These lead to
>   accidental direct mutation, and should be avoided.

You can do this manually, something like:

```
function updateVeryNestedField(state, action) {
    return {
        ....state,
        first : {
            ...state.first,
            second : {
                ...state.first.second,
                [action.someId] : {
                    ...state.first.second[action.someId],
                    fourth : action.someValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In practice, it's better to use a helper library to do this. You can find a list of helper libraries at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities, I would personally recommend [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) or just switching to [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: I read that too, but I can't understand why I have to do that? Because when I do a deep copy of the old state, no references exists and I should be able to just change one property somewhere in the state which will make a diff.
Because in the chrome redux extension, it was a correct diff.

Comment: `let newState = Object.assign({}, state);` does not do a deep copy, it's only a shallow copy: `newState` is a new reference, but `newState.coupons === state.coupons`

Comment: Well, what if I use the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldState));
Shouldn't that work? Because I just tried and it did not work. I have no idea why, because it is supposed to make a deep copy;

Comment: That should work, as it creates a deep copy, so there might be something else wrong with your system. Hard to give concrete advice without a test case.

Comment: Can it be because my mapStateToProps function is incorrect? I've updated my original question with it.

Comment: Deep copies are bad, because they will cause re-renders in components that are looking at _any_ of that data, not just components that care about the one specific piece.  See the related Redux FAQ entry at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-clone-state .  Also, as author of the Redux FAQ, the "Structuring Reducers" section, and that list of addons... @OlliM  is totally correct here :)